# Trying to fill in date gaps in mysql

Tags: mysql, date

I have been struggling with this issue for awhile and cant quite get this to work

I have the following tables

Calendar - contains dates for 50 years

```
+-------+------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Date  | date | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+-------+------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Markets - a list of divisions and markets belonging to those divisions i.e. a division contains multiple markets but a market belongs to a single division

```
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ID       | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| Market   | varchar(255) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |                |
| Division | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Total Monthly Case Counts - contains a count of issues opened for a particular platform in a market and division for a given month

```
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Case Month | varchar(10)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Division   | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Market     | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Platform   | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Count      | bigint(21)   | NO   |     | 0       |       |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I am trying to produce a list which includes every month in the calendar, every division, every market and the count of each platform

`2012-01-01 Central Atlanta     Type A  3
2012-01-01  Central Atlanta     Type B  0
2012-01-01  Central Michigan    Type A  1
2012-01-01  Central Michigan    Type B  1
2012-01-01  Central Nashville   Type A  0
2012-01-01  Central Nashville   Type B  1`

The problem is the Total Monthly Case Counts only contains values for dates and platforms which exist
If a case is not counted for a given platform in a market and division in a given month there is no record. In the above desired output the 0 values do not exist.

I have been trying to join the calendar table to the total monthly case table but can never get all divisions and markets to show for every month, let alone include a 0 count if the record really doesn't exist in total monthly case table.
I have made it this far but its not padding the divisions, markets and platforms

```
    SELECT
    Calendar.Date AS Date,
    `Total Monthly Case Count`.Division,
    `Total Monthly Case Count`.Market,
    `Total Monthly Case Count`.Platform,
    IFNULL(`Total Monthly Case Count`.Count,0) AS Count
    FROM
    Calendar
    LEFT JOIN `Total Monthly Case Count` ON Calendar.Date = `Total Monthly Case Count`.`Case Month` ,
    Markets
    WHERE
    (Calendar.`Date` BETWEEN (SELECT MIN(`Total Monthly Case Count`.`Case Month`) FROM `Total Monthly Case Count`) AND (SELECT MAX(`Total Monthly Case Count`.`Case Month`) FROM `Total Monthly Case Count`)) AND Calendar.`Date` = `Total Monthly Case Count`.`Case Month`
    ORDER BY
    Date ASC,
    Markets.Division ASC,
    Markets.Market ASC
```

This produces the below result

`2012-01-01 Central Atlanta     Type A  3
2012-01-01  Central Michigan    Type A  1
2012-01-01  Central Nashville   Type A  1
2012-01-01  Central Pompano     Type A  1
2012-01-01  East    BAD         Type B  1
2012-01-01  East    BAD         Type A  2
2012-01-01  East    BAD         Type C  1`

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: For the love of humanity, don't include spaces in table/column names. This will drive you mad. And change WHERE to AND

Comment: I'm not really sure how this solves my issue?